# Troubles to access Google storage buckets in Python

Tags: google-cloud-storage

With the same service account I can list objects in the shell without a problem, i.e.
`gsutil ls gs://{bucket-name}` works just fine. But when I tried to work with the Python client using below code, it threw me a 403 error

```
import os
from google.cloud import storage

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "path-to-credential"
client = storage.Client()

for bucket in client.list_buckets():
    print(bucket)

# error
Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=project-name&projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: ml-service-account@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.
```

not sure which part I did wrong, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your code, the error points to your service account that you are using:

```
ml-service-account@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.
```

Make sure that your **service account** has a role with **"Owner"**, **"Editor"**, **"Viewer"** or **"storage.admin"** role on [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) of your project.

Comment: @chchann let me know if you have question or clarification in my answer